# Flask Jinja 2 Rendering Issue

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am sure I am doing something wrong .

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.username.label }}<br>
            {{ form.username(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.password.label }}<br>
            {{ form.password(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.remember_me() }} {{ form.remember_me.label }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Above code gives this output:

[image]

Which is correct.  But  when i change same code to as below :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.username.label }}<br>
            {{ form.username(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.password.label }}<br>
            {{ form.password(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.remember_me() }} {{ form.remember_me.label }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Output becomes like this:

[image]

My base.html looks like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="/index">Home</a>
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
</div>
```

I am sure , i am making some silly mistake but can not seem to find it .

if i copy the code from base.html on top of my code it renders correctly.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Don't know why it was down voted, wrong tags ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a content block to override in your `base.html`

```
<div>
    <a href="/index">Home</a>
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
    {% block content %}{%endblock%}
</div>
```

Your `base.html` should contain blocks in it for the various content blocks that you will have in your site.
When you create a new page and want to override that content or add content to those blocks you use extends like you have done.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    Your content goes here
{% endblock %}
```

You can have multiple blocks in your `base.html` and then override them when you want.
[Jinja documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)

You can put content in the content blocks in your base html and then add to that content without overriding it using the `super()` function.

```
{% block content %}
    {{ super() }}
    New content here
{% endblock %}
```

The above can be handy for script files. If you have some that need to be site wide, and some only on specific pages.